# How to Prepare a Prepared Statement With Lots of If Statements?

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I have about 25 optional field for my sql query. What I am doing is, posting the data using ajax (for pagination) to another php file to prepare and execute the query.

**Sample (index.php)**

```
// Get optional value
if (isset($_POST['il']) && !empty($_POST['il'])) $il = $_POST['il'];
// JS
change_page('0');
});

function change_page(page_id) {
 var dataString = page_id;
// Define optional value
 <?php if (isset($_POST['il'])&& !empty($_POST['il'])):?>
 var il = '<?php echo $il;?>';
 <?php endif; ?>

 // Send optional value
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/post.php",
    data: {
    <?php if (isset($_POST['il'])&& !empty($_POST['il'])):?>'il': il,<?php endif; ?>  },
...
```

**Post.php (Where operations are handled)**

```
...
// Main Query (default)
$bas_query = "SELECT id, a, b, c, d, e FROM test.db WHERE a=$1 AND b=$2";

// If user has an input for 'il', add it to query.
    if (isset($_POST['il']) && !empty($_POST['il'])) {
        $il = $_POST['il'];
        $bas_query. = ' AND city='.$il;
}

// How it's executed after statements (without ifs included)
$exec = pg_prepare($postgre,'sql2', 'SELECT id, a, b, c, d, e FROM test.db WHERE a=$1 AND b=$2 OFFSET $3 LIMIT $4');
$exec = pg_execute($postgre,'sql2', array($1,$2,$3,$4));
```

My question is, how could I prepare a prepared statement with a lot of if statements? I can concatenate and prepare the `pg_prepare`'s query, but then how will assign the values before executing the query in the right order?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It sounds like you have a database that hasn't been normalized.

Comment: @e4c5 I'm sorry but, how come? Database is perfectly normal (which does not belong to me of course :-)) I just can't figure out the easiest way to include optional parameters into my final query using prepared statements

Comment: a table with 25 columns sounds a bit strange

Comment: @e4c5 Oh, you are definitely right on this but it has to. It has about 25M~ records, but interestingly its pretty efficient

Comment: Put them in an array, then use it in your `pg_execute`, I don't think you'll have to deal with order with this way.

Comment: @A.MesutKonuklar Could you please explain how insert the via array without interrupting the order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this method

```
// Change your query to below
$bas_query = "SELECT id, a, b, c, d, e FROM test.db WHERE";

// Initiate your array and counter for prepared statement
$data = array();
$counter = 1;

// I assume you assigned a and b value same as below
...
// Add data to the array for each case
if (isset($_POST['il']) && !empty($_POST['il']))
    {
    $il = $_POST['il'];
    $bas_query.= ' AND city=$' . $counter;
    $counter++;
    $data[] = $il;
    } 
... /* other if statements */
// To prepare and execute the statement; (after all the if statements)
/* A) concatenate OFFSET and LIMIT end of your final query
   B) insert the OFFSET and LIMIT value to the array       */
$bas_query.= ' OFFSET $' . $counter . ' LIMIT $' . ($counter + 1);
$data[] = $your_offset_val;
$data[] = $your_limit_val;

$exec = pg_prepare($postgre, 'sql2', $bas_query);
$exec = pg_execute($postgre, 'sql2', $data);
```

You would have the following output

```
SELECT id, a, b, c, d, e FROM test.db WHERE a=$1 AND b=$2 AND city=$3 OFFSET $4 LIMIT $5

Array ( [0] => a_value [1] => b_value [2] => city_value [3] => offset_value [4] => limit_value )
```